# Deserializing different object types from a MemoryStream efficiently

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to manually deserialize objects from a `MemoryStream`, but the `MemoryStream` will have different object types in it and I need to call an appropriate method depending on the object type. For example, this is how the `MemoryStream` is formatted (object type then data, repeating):

```
[object type (uint)][object data (variable length)][object type (uint)][object data (variable length)][object type (uint)][object data (variable length)]
```

Given the object type, I know how much data to expect and read for that object type. The problem that I have is figuring out an efficient way to read that data.

One way would be to use a switch statement like this:

```
switch (objectType) {
    case 0:
        SomeClass.LoadFromMemoryStream(memoryStream);
        break;
    case 1:
        SomeOtherClass.LoadFromMemoryStream(memoryStream);
        break;
    case 2:
        EvenAnotherClass.LoadFromMemoryStream(memoryStream);
        break;
    ...
}
```

Each of the different classes will obviously need their own method to load the data from the memory stream and advance the pointer however many bytes is appropriate for that object type.

This seems difficult to maintain when there are hundreds of types of objects that can be loaded this way, and somewhat inefficient if for each object in the stream, it has to iterate through a case statement with hundreds of types to determine what to call.

I suspect that I can do this with generics but don't understand how to set up the classes and methods to support this. Is a switch statement the best approach? If not, what is?

Comment: Making a game over TCP? ^^ Not usually a good idea.

Comment: Making a game, but this is for loading a map from a file. The map is already loaded into memory by using a byte array, and I'm using a MemoryStream to easily read its data using functions like ReadUInt16()

Comment: why don't you load the map from disk? Also, why don't you use 4-byte length mark for each variable-length object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, I will do the following. 
1.Define an interface,

```
public interface ISerializableType
{
    uint TypeIdentity { get; }

    void InitFromStream(Stream stream);

    void ToStream(Stream stream);
}
```

2.Let all the types that you need to support to implement this interface.
3.Create a factory class, register all the object types that you need to support

```
private IDictionary<uint, System.Type> _objectMap = new Dictionary<uint, System.Type>();
```

4.When to are reading information from the stream, first of all check the type identity, and then check against your container to see whether you can support it or not, if you can , then grab the type and create an new object.

5.Cast the new object to an ISerializableType, and call the InitFromStream method.

```
var typeIdentity = ReadIdentityFromStream(stream);
        if(_objectMap.ContainsKey(typeIdentity)){
            var type = _objectMap[typeIdentity];
            var obj = System.Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            var iSerializable = obj as ISerializableType;
            if (null != iSerializable) iSerializable.InitFromStream(stream);
        };
```

I hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding efficiency. Check [protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/).

And regarding the problem. You should not operate with array of objects alone when saving/loading a state. It should be a complete type, which performs all necessary steps upon deserialization on its own.

To example, deserializing this

```
object[] mydata;
```

would required from you a switch case or running a method to detect types of objects (long and hard to maintain switch), you could actually utilize attributes to tell what to do with which object, but..

Consider this

```
public class Level
{
    public IItem[] Item {get; set;}
    public IRoom[] Room {get; set;}
    public IMonster[] Monster {get; set;}
    ...
}

public class ItemBook: IItem
{
    public string Name
    {
        set { /* this code will be automatically executed during deserialization */ }
    }

    public ItemBook()
    {
        /* and this code */ 
    }
}

...
```

Deserializing `Level` is more efficient.